# PowerPoint 2011: How to Insert image with "crop to fit" by default?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft

I am preparing technical presentations with a lot of graphics using PowerPoint 2011 for Mac (version 14.4.9).
Whenever I insert an image, it is set to **crop to fill** by default (the most useless option in my opinion). 
Here is how the default option looks like:
[image: The default behavior is **crop to fill**]

Then, it turns out that for every image, I have to manually set it to **crop to fit** and resize the container box correctly. Just to look like that:
[image: Desired default behavior]

Is there a way to override this default behavior to get the inserted images as they are without any funny cropping?

I tried to research the problem, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use the "Placeholder" in PowerPoint.

1. Use View → Slide Master, then choose your layout.
2. Select "Insert Placeholder" and choose Picture.
3. Use the cursor to drag the picture to size and position it.

You can make multiple placeholders, but you do not have to use all of them if a slide does not require it.

From now on all new slides (with the chosen layout) will have the placeholders where you can insert a picture and they all will be cropped to auto fit the placeholder, or auto fill.

[image: Screenshot of PowerPoint showing Insert Placeholder button selected]

What you are trying to do is not possible. The Crop to fill will take the original and without shrinking it will use the center part and fill it in the preassigned Place Holder. The crop to fit will have to reduce the original to show it as whole in preassigned place holder.

Here is an example (left and right are place holders) while the middle is the original. So even if using the crop to fit as default the image size will be what your place holder was. Thus using the Crop to Fill is better option while using the Crop tool to move to the part of the image you wanted to show in full size.

The problem with your request is that the Crop to Fit will always require adjustment depending on the original image size.

[image: Picasso in Malaga]

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am familiar with that already. I updated my question to reflect exactly what I want to achieve. Still the picture place holder will always do a **Crop to fill** by default. That is what I want to change to make it **Crop to fit**.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. So, there is no way to just put an image there: i.e., like in the regular Power Point on Windows, where you just paste/drop/insert a picture and it is there without any funny cropping?

Comment: There is, see the middle pic, it is based on the original without adjustments. Still it will be auto fitted to the PP page size, so if you have a very large pic and and you use the place in original size/resolution, it will be placed exceeding the page size. That is the same on Windows PP.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CONTENT placeholder (and insert using the image icon) rather than a PICTURE placeholder.  The content placeholder should automatically fit the entire image within the placeholder, whereas a picture placeholder will crop the image to whatever size and shape the placeholder has been created as.